# Devise gem in Rails: generate user_root_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Trying to redirect users to their associated 'home' page after successful login w/out nil'ing out `stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)`...which is giving me some endless redirect loops *(pretty sure I've set it up wrong)*.

Regardless, I'm looking for a better approach...

> [Devise's docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller) state: After
>   signing in a user, confirming the
>   account or updating the password,
>   Devise will look for a scoped root
>   path to redirect. Example: For a
>   `:user` resource, it will use
>   `user_root_path` if it exists,
>   otherwise default `root_path` will be
>   used. This means that you need to set
>   the root inside your routes: `root :to => "home"`

I'm sorta a newbie...how does one go about generating this `home_root_path` for each user?

[rDocs also mention](http://rubydoc.info/gems/devise/1.1.5/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for):

> -- (Object) **after_sign_in_path_for**(resource_or_scope)
>
> The default url to be used after
>   signing in. This is used by all Devise
>   controllers and you can overwrite it
>   in your ApplicationController to
>   provide a custom hook for a custom
>   resource.
>        By default, it first tries to find a resource_root_path, otherwise
>   it uses the root path. For a user
>   scope, you can define the default url
>   in the following way:
>
> ```
>  map.user_root '/users', :controller => 'users' # creates user_root_path
>
>  map.namespace :user do |user|
>    user.root :controller => 'users' # creates user_root_path
>  end
> ```

but these just gives me `undefined local variable or method`map' for #ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:…` errors.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  The after_sign_in_path_for bits above are using rails 2.x routing syntax.  If you're using rails 3.x, then they could cause problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

application_controller.rb:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  # return home_page_path for user using current_user method
end
```

Comment: Rick derived his answer from this one.  See my comment under Rick's answer for a possible gotcha.

Answer (score 24):

If you would like to redirect using a route in answer to your question below:

> how does one go about generating this home_root_path for each user?

This will work if you place it in your config/routes file.  It will redirect a user to articles#index after (for example) a successful confirmation.

```
    # Rails 4+
    get 'user_root' => 'articles#index', as: :user_root

    # Rails 3
    match 'user_root' => 'articles#index', as: :user_root
```

See [Devise: Controllers Filters and Helpers](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Comment: In Ruby 1.8, the syntax is a little different: `:as => :user_root`

Comment: I tried it without the `:as`, and it seems to work the same. Is there any advantage to including the `:as`?

Comment: Ten! years later, and this is the only solution that seems to allow taking control over Devise's `signed_in_root_path()`.   Of all the hooks they provide, they don't seem to provide a way to properly override the behavior of this function.

Answer (score 6):

Dug around a bit to figure out the same thing. @polarblau's answer is correct,

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  user_info_path(current_user)
end
```

where user_info_path is the path to the page you wish to display.

Also, I would allow this to fall back to super just in case, although I'm not entirely sure if that is necessary...

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a(User)
    user_info_path(resource)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: This works for me although I changed it to resource.is_a?(User)

Comment: This approach always goes to the same path on signin, but I discovered that it also overrides Devise's built-in ability to return to a path after a session timeout. I.e. Devise automatically stores `session[:user_return_to]` on signout, but if you set the `after_sign_in_path_for` as shown here, that session variable is ignored. Using the `user_root` route approach as in SnapShot's answer lets you do both:  go to the `user_return_to` location if one is defined in the session, else go to the path defined as the `root_path`.

Answer (score 1):

I spent several hours trying to get the same functionality, and this is the code that ended up working for me:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    current_user
end
```

If I ever tried `current_user_path`, I always got `undefined local variable or method current_user_path` errors.

Also, I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Devise 2.1.2.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @SnapShot answer, this worked for me. I'm using multiple devise models, trying to redirect back to the users profile edit page.

```
  get 'user_root', to: redirect('/users/edit'), as: :user_root
```

Answer (score 0):

ROR 7 answer

```
 get '/users/home' => 'application#test', as: :user_root
```